# Undecorated JFrame shows undesired icons

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've written a simple program like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyFirstJavaProgram");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When the frame is minimized (by clicking on its icon in the taskbar) and then restored, it shows undesired icons like title bar icons (close icon, minimize and maximize) and then shows undecorated JFrame.

Here is a video of my problem: http://www.mediafire.com/file/k2uzd0b8uupd1h9/Video.mp4/file you can see icons in **top-left corner** that flash for a very short time and then disappear.

Is this a bug? how can I solve this problem? I am using JDK 13 and my OS is Win8.1

Comment: As someone told you [the first time you posted this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866781/undecorated-jframe-shows-undesired-icons), all Swing methods need to be run on the AWT event dispatch thread, not the main thread.  Move all of your code into the `run` method of a Runnable, and pass that Runnable to [EventQueue.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Comment: @VGR I tried that too.  It doesn't fix the  problem.  But the images of the icons are only there for a fraction of a second.   I didn't even see them when I first tried this.

Comment: @VGR:can you write my simple code in the form of what you mean and then post it to me? many thanks

Comment: @WJS: Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You could just use a `JWindow`, perhaps.  But the almost invisible flash I see is not that worrisome to me so I wouldn't care about it.  Not certain if you can unminimize a JWindow though.

Comment: @WJS: Unfortunately JWindow is not an alternative to JFrame, because it doesn't show any icon in the taskbar

Answer (score 0):

I think this might solve your problem.  I created a window listener to watch for the window to be unminimized.  Then I set the window invisible for a few milliseconds and then reset it to visible.  If it doesn't work, you might want to bump up the value to `Thread.sleep()`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities
                .invokeLater(() -> new Testit().start()); // starts on the EDT.
    }

    public void start() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(
                JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addWindowListener(
                new MyWindowListener(frame));

    }

    private class MyWindowListener extends WindowAdapter {
        JFrame frame;

        public MyWindowListener(JFrame frame) {
            this.frame = frame;
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent we) {
            frame.setVisible(false);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately when the frame visibility sets to false and then to true, JFrame's icon in the taskbar moves a little to right and then moves to left.

Comment: I was focusing on the icons and didn't notice. Not much I can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

@WJS: In fact I had reached a solution in the past, very similar to your approach. but to solve your code problem (moving Jframe icon in the taskbar) I added a window listener to my frame like this and I used Opacity instead of Visibility, I also used WindowActivated instead of  WindowDeiconified:

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } 
                catch(InterruptedException ex) {}
                frame.setOpacity(1f);
            }
            @Override
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
                frame.setOpacity(0f);
            }
        });
```

this works fine. but my main question is that: Why do I have to do some stuff like this? what's the source of this ugly thing? However JDK has reached to 13th version but this bug has still remained.